# Exiting a windows form application from a form other than the main form

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to exit the application from a form other than the one that is first opened by the application. Whenever I do this however it pops the same form up again but this one does not respond. The debug gives this error:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

I've tried looking up the method but I can't find anything that I'm trying to do.

```
private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
```

there are up to 7 other forms open at the same time. This includes the main (first) form.

I expect the application to exit fully, but it just pops up another copy of its self and then the debug gives the error listed above.

Comment: do you have some code in `FormClosing` or similar events?

Comment: @S.Serpooshan I do not have a `FormClosing` event and this is the only form with an `Application.Exit()` other than the first form which also has a button exiting the application. The first form's works.

Comment: what if you try `this.Close();` before calling `Application.Exit();`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this line 
Application.ExitThread();